# How to load data from url in Kepler?

Tags: kepler.gl

After embedding kepler.gl into my application, how can I add the feature of adding the data from url? By default, I am able to add csv file into the modal of kepler.

Answer (score 0):

from the kepler.gl dashboard initial page use the 'Load map uising url' and point your csv there. Reference screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way but i actually trying to get it work with multiple data:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
keplerGl: keplerGlReducer,
});

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(taskMiddleware));

const mapboxApiAccessToken = "YOUR-API-KEY";

export default function Keplerglcomp() {
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Map/>
    </Provider>
);
}

function Map() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const {data} = useSwr("datacap", async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
        
"https://placeholder.com/data.json"
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
})


React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        dispatch(
            addDataToMap({
                datasets: {
                    info: {
                        label: "Datalabel-1",
                        id: "Dataid-1"
                    },
                    data
                },
                option: {
                    centerMap: true,
                    readOnly: true
                },
                config: {}
            }),
        );
    }

}, [dispatch, data]);

return (
    <div>
        <AutoSizer>
            {({height, width}) => (
                <KeplerGl
                    id="magic"
                    mapboxApiAccessToken={mapboxApiAccessToken}
                    width={window.innerWidth}
                    height={window.innerHeight}
                />
            )}
        </AutoSizer>
    </div>
);
}
```